# Show Log In user time details

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to show user log in time details.I have two table.One is UserMaster which contains UserDetails and one is UserLogInTimeDetails contains two columns UserId and LogedInTime.
When User Log in UserId and LogInTime stores in UserLogInTimeDetails.
When User Log Off I am deleting the row of that particular user from UserLogInTimeDetails.

But the problem is if an user close the browser then the details of the user in not deleted from UserLogInTimeDetails table.For which that user will not be able to log in again.

How to solve this issue?
I have googled and saw that browser close event in not possible to handle and in many places they have adviced to use onbeforeunload event which is not working for me.

Please help. I am in big trouble.

Comment: can you please paste code. What you have done so far ?

Comment: This is a classic problem, probably your best approach is to have some sort of LastActivity and time it out

Comment: Don't include tags in title!!

Comment: If any answer has helped you, please accept the one of them. Stackoverflow is built on user reputation, which makes the answers to all questions better. =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could get it working using Session_End in your global.asax file to remove the user when their session expires. Though I'm not 100% sure if you can get the session ID from this method. It may be within the EventArgs...

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Remove user from database here
}
```

Else, another way to store the data is based on last activity, so everytime the user submits a request you update the time of last activity. You could even store this with a session ID in the database along with their login time, and then be able to calculate the duration active from login time to last activity for that session;

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that the user cannot login multiple times from different browsers?

If not, a more common approach is to store a login information variable in a session variable (maybe login time, user id or something like that), and use it to verify if the user has logged in or not.

If the user close the browser the session is lost, and he must login again, but he can login as many times as he wishes from different browsers.

You can access these variables like this:

```
// Set it like this. Can be any type of object with login data.
Session["LoginData"] = "Hello";

// Get it like this.
string test = (string)Session["LoginData"];
```

Edit:
If it is important that the user must nog login multiple times, you have a much bigger problem to solve.
Maybe something like this could be the solution?

- Let the browser (via ajax) ping the web server somehow, every few seconds or so (how many depends on how long you want the browser to be shut down before it is ok to login again vs. traffic)
- When the server receives a ping from a certain user, stamp the date and time in a session variable.
- If a browser is trying to access the web page in any way, first, check for the session and for how long time ago the last ping was done. If the session is null, or the time is more than the time between pings*2 (or something like that) the user can login again (send to login page). If the time is shorter check if the user is logged in. If he is, continue. If not, tell him he must log out from the first connection (or whatever you want).

Hope this helps!

Comment: No one user can log in only once at a time

Comment: Ok, I am very sorry, but since the web today is not a stream of data flowing back and forward (as in a TCP/IP connection), I believe it is difficult to implement this. The server will not know when the user closes the browser.

Comment: user3193557: I have edited the comment for an approach where the user must be logged in only once.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go with this using signalR. You can track user is online or offline. based on even dispose you can track exact logout or browser close too.

Hope this will teach you something new. refer below link for a simple example of signalR.

[signalR sample application for online, offline status](http://lonetechie.com/2012/12/24/who-is-online-with-signalr-a-sample-project/)